# All list item versions return the current list item version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to iterate over list item versions, to get any change in versions, but unfortunately I always get the same current version data, unless the VersionLabel.

```
  if(versions.Count > 0 && termes.EnableVersioning)
  {
     for (int index = 0 ; index < versions.Count ; index++)
     {

        string var1 = versions[index].VersionLabel;

        string  var2 =       
              versions[index].ListItem["fieldiinternalnamename1"];

        string var3 = 
             versions[index].ListItem["fieldiinternalnamename2"];

        string var4 = 
             versions[index].ListItem["fieldiinternalnamename3"];


         }
     }
```

my complete code is:

```
 if(versions.Count > 0 && termes.EnableVersioning)
 {
     for (int index = 0 ; index < versions.Count ; index++)
     {

         //second tabe for version titles
         table = new PdfPTable(6);
         table.TotalWidth = 520f;
         table.LockedWidth = true;

         table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
         table.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

         bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, 
         BaseFont.CP1252, false);
         font = new Font(bfTimes, 7, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

         //modifier
         cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(versions[index].VersionLabel, 
          font));
         cell.PaddingLeft = 0;
         cell.PaddingRight = 0;
         cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

         cell.Border = 0;

         table.AddCell(cell);
         //modifier
         cell = new PdfPCell(new  

    Phrase(versions[index].ListItem
    [ConstVariables2.Terme_Modifier_par2_encodé] != null ?   
     versions[index].ListItem
   [ConstVariables2.Terme_Modifier_par2_encodé].ToString().Trim()
   .Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1] : "", font));
         cell.PaddingLeft = 0;
         cell.PaddingRight = 0;
         cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

         cell.Border = 0;

         table.AddCell(cell);

         //title
         cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(versions[index].ListItem.Title, 
         font));
         cell.PaddingLeft = 0;
         cell.PaddingRight = 0;
         cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

         cell.Border = 0;

         table.AddCell(cell);

         //english
         cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(versions[index].ListItem
         [ConstVariables2.Terme_Anglais2_encodé] != null ?   
          versions[index].ListItem
         [ConstVariables2.Terme_Anglais2_encodé].ToString().Trim() : "", 
          font));
         cell.PaddingLeft = 0;
         cell.PaddingRight = 0;
         cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

         cell.Border = 0;

         table.AddCell(cell);

         //french
         cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(versions[index].ListItem
        [ConstVariables2.Terme_Francais2_encodé] != null ? 
         versions[index].ListItem
        [ConstVariables2.Terme_Francais2_encodé].ToString().Trim() : "", 
        font));
         cell.PaddingLeft = 0;
         cell.PaddingRight = 0;
         cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

            cell.Border = 0;

           table.AddCell(cell);

         //deutsch
         cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(versions[index].ListItem
        [ConstVariables2.Terme_Allemand2_encodé] != null ? 
        versions[index].ListItem
        [ConstVariables2.Terme_Allemand2_encodé].ToString().Trim() : "", 
          font));
         cell.PaddingLeft = 0;
         cell.PaddingRight = 0;
         cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

         cell.Border = 0;

            table.AddCell(cell);

         //arabic
         bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 
         BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
           font = new Font(bfTimes, 9, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

         cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(versions[index].ListItem
         [ConstVariables2.Terme_Arabe2_encodé] != null ? 
          versions[index].ListItem
         [ConstVariables2.Terme_Arabe2_encodé].ToString().Trim() : "", 
         font));
         cell.PaddingLeft = 0;
         cell.PaddingRight = 0;
         cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
         //cell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;

         cell.Border = 0;

         table.AddCell(cell);

         table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, doc.Left, height, 
         writer.DirectContent);


      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is not correct. You can overwriting the variables.

Try below

```
if(versions.Count > 0 && termes.EnableVersioning)
{
    List<string> var1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> var2 = new List<string>();
    List<string> var3 = new List<string>();
    List<string> var4 = new List<string>();
    for (int index = 0 ; index < versions.Count ; index++)
    {
        var1.Add(versions[index].VersionLabel);
        var2.Add(versions[index].ListItem["fieldiinternalnamename1"].ToString());
        var3.Add(versions[index].ListItem["fieldiinternalnamename2"].ToString());
        var4.Add(versions[index].ListItem["fieldiinternalnamename3"].ToString());
    }

    //HERE Iterate through the list
}
```

Comment: thanks mr hashim why is not correct because i'm trying to iterate on versions and display each iiteration (or version) on table row to be printed in pdf file

Comment: There was no code to do tat. so i assumed.. please post complete code

Answer (score 0):

the correct response is ; use the internalname to the version object directly :

```
 if(versions.Count > 0 && termes.EnableVersioning)
 {
   for (int index = 0 ; index < versions.Count ; index++)
   {

    string var1 = versions[index].VersionLabel;

    string  var2 =       
          versions[index]["fieldiinternalnamename1"];

    string var3 = 
         versions[index]["fieldiinternalnamename2"];

    string var4 = 
         versions[index]["fieldiinternalnamename3"];


     }
 }
```